# When and by whom was the Tirupati Tirumala temple in India built?

Tags: india

India's second wealthiest temple, [Tirupati Tirumala Venkateswara Temple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirupati_Temple#History_of_the_temple) does not seem to have a clear history about its origin. The Wikipedia entry does not provide proper details on who exactly built this temple atop a mountain or the approximate date when it was built. Even if it were disputed, there must be historians' educated guesses and opinions on this.

Could someone flesh out these details from a reliable source?

Answer (score 2):

The deity itself is self-formed or swayambhu. Raja Thondaman (Thondaman Chakravarty) chiefly contributed to building the temple. [Krishnadevaraya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishnadevaraya) is also said to have made several endowments to the temple.

[Venkatachala Mahatmayam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_Tirumala) is the book of reference for history of TTD.

Comment: Which deity is considered self-formed?

Comment: The deity enshrined in the TTD temple- Venkateswara Swamy

Comment: Do you mean to say [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lord_Venkateswara.jpg) statue formed all by itself ?

Answer (score 1):

1) The Temple is Built by Tamil pallava King Thondaiman.
2) The Temple has tamil scripts around the inner walls.

Comment: Assuming 1 is meant to be an answer to "when" using reginal dates, and 2 is meant to provide a possible an answer to "by whom", this seems like a direct answer to me. Could use some cleanup perhaps, but its an answer.

Comment: @T.E.D. 1 is meant be an answer by whom, and 2 is not an answer but information to emphasize that it was built by a Tamil (language) King.

Answer (score -2):

Tirupati Tirumala Venkateswara Temple would have been build around the time when Puri Jagannath tample was build because moto of both temple is same.

Comment: Could you please provide some source(s) to substantiate this information?